# Unable to retrieve data from frame

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, data-science

I am trying to retrieve specific data from data-frame with particular condition, but it show empty data frame. I am new to data science, trying to learn data science. Here is my code.

```
file = open('/home/jeet/files1/files/ch03/adult.data', 'r')
def chr_int(a):
    if a.isdigit(): return int(a)
    else: return 0

data = []
for line in file:
    data1 = line.split(',')
    if len(data1) == 15:
        data.append([chr_int(data1[0]), data1[1],
                   chr_int(data1[2]), data1[3],
                   chr_int(data1[4]), data1[5],
                   data1[6], data1[7], data1[8],
                   data1[9], chr_int(data1[10]),
                   chr_int(data1[11]),
                   chr_int(data1[12]),
                   data1[13], data1[14]])

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.columns = ['age', 'type-employer', 'fnlwgt', 'education','education_num', 'marital','occupation', 'relationship','race','sex','capital_gain','capital_loss','hr_per_week','country','income']

ml = df[(df.sex == 'Male')] # here i retrive data who is male
ml1 = df[(df.sex == 'Male') & (df.income == '>50K\n')]
print(ml1.head()) # here i printing that data
fm =df[(df.sex == 'Female')]
fm1 = df [(df.sex == 'Female') & (df.income =='>50K\n')]
```

output:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [age, type-employer, fnlwgt, education, education_num, marital, occupation, relationship, race, sex, capital_gain, capital_loss, hr_per_week, country, income]
Index: []
```

what's wrong with the code. why data frame is empty.

Comment: Are you sue that values in 'income' column are strings and contain '\n'?

Comment: yes, they are string.

Comment: Then try this: print(df.income.unique()). Do printed values have '\n' in them?

Comment: I tried to remove '\n' but still. same output.

Comment: I got this output: [' <=50K\n' ' >50K\n']

Comment: And here is the problem! If you look carefully, you'll notice that there is a space in front of each value. So either use the following: ml1 = df[(df.sex == 'Male') & (df.income == ' >50K\n')] fm1 = df [(df.sex == 'Female') & (df.income ==' <=50K\n')], or process the values and get rid of spaces.

Comment: It might be beneficial to use pandas.read_csv. Might save a step or two: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html  
Also, if you add several rows of the data, it will help others help you.

Comment: Thank you so much sir, I really appreciate your help. @ Andrey Lukyanenko

Comment: Then I'll write my answer separately.

Answer (score 0):

If you check the values carefully, you may see the problem:

```
print(df.income.unique())
>>> [' <=50K\n' ' >50K\n']
```

There are spaces in front of each values. So values should be either processed to get rid of these spaces, or the code should be modified like this:

```
ml1 = df[(df.sex == 'Male') & (df.income == ' >50K\n')]
fm1 = df [(df.sex == 'Female') & (df.income ==' <=50K\n')]
```